# How to configure Ipv4 settings on Server 2012 R2, for offline LAN and online wireless connectivity?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns, windows-server-2012-r2, teamviewer

I have a bit of an odd situation that I'm hoping someone can help me out with.

Let's say I have a domain controller with Windows Server 2012 R2, let's call it DCSERVER, and there's a 2nd Server 2012 R2 machine that stores a bunch of files, called STORAGESERVER.  STORAGESERVER looks to DCSERVER for DNS, and these two machines are connected via local ethernet cables, and have no internet connectivity since the wired connections are just connected to each other only with a small local network switch.

For simplicity sake, lets say DCSERVER has an ip address of 192.168.1.1, and STORAGESERVER has an ip address of 192.168.1.2

I want to be able to plug in a wireless adapter, and be able to have that communicate with a wireless router (specifically so that I can remotely connect to the machine via remote control software like TeamViewer).  I've enabled wireless functionality on the servers, but the problem for example is when I connect to a wireless network with STORAGESERVER, although it has internet connectivity, it "loses" connectivity to the DCSERVER, since it's now using the wireless connection and I guess it gives up on the local connection to DCSERVER that is not connected to the internet.

Is there a way for me to maintain both the wireless internet connectivity for remote control purposes, while also maintaining the wired local connection between the two machines that is not internet-connected?

If you could help explain how I need to set this screen, that would be helpful:

[image: IPv4ConfigScreen]

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Couple suggestions/options:

1. Ensure your Wi-Fi network is a different network/subnet than the network between the two servers (since they ARE two different networks); that way there will be no routing confusion within the StorageServer.
2. On the StorageServer, add a specific route to DCServer, using the specific interface (run `Route Add /?` in a command prompt for more info).

You may need to use a combination of the two.